# Probability from sample size

Tags: statistics

I am working on taking a methodology class and when working on past exams I stumbled over this question. I used $n=\frac{z^2*Var}{error^2}$ to obtain the variance; however, I have no idea to obtain the probability from that without a mean.

Suppose we are interested in what percentage of students in a group of $10,000$ would recommend their school to others. Furthermore, suppose we want to be 99% sure that the error from our sample of respondents is no more than four percentage points and the computed minimum sample size is $373$. What percentage of students did we expect to be willing to recommend their school?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the Normal Approximation the the binomial, we can determine the minimum sample size according to:

$$n = \left(\frac{z^*}{m}\right)^2p^*(1-p^*)$$

Where $p^*$ is the percentage of students "we expect to be willing to recommend their school". We rearrange and fill in the information that we have.

$$p^*(1-p^*) = n\frac{m^2}{{z^*}^2} = \frac{373\cdot (.04)^2}{2.576^2} \approx .09$$

Solving for $p^*$ we get the solutions $p^* = 0.9$ or $p^* = 0.1$. Either one is an acceptable answer with the information given.